# discord bot can join channel but can't play music

Tags: discord, discord.js, audio-player

I am making a discord music bot in JavaScript, and the bot can join voice channels fine, but it won’t play any music

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytsearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
name:'play',
description: 'joins and plays a video from youtube',
async execute(message, args) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a vc to play music');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You do not have the correct permission to perform this action');
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You do not have the correct permissions to perform this action');
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('Please inclue something for me to play');
    
    const {
        joinVoiceChannel,
        createAudioPlayer,
        createAudioResource
    } = require('@discordjs/voice');

    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
        guildId: message.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });
    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

        return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
    const stream = ytdl(video.url, {
        filter: "audioonly"
    });

    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

    async function play() {
        await player.play(resource);
        connection.subscribe(player);
    }
}
}}
```

Comment: Error doesn't correspond to the code are there any more errors below it?

Comment: No there’s no other errors

Comment: I can send my main code file to see if the error is in there, but I assumed it was in here because it only occurs when I try and do the play command

Comment: The error you received has to do with the message event: `client.on("message", ...)`. So you need to replace `message` with `messageCreate`

Comment: The error message no longer comes up but it still doesn’t play any music

Comment: Attach your main bot's file as well please